# Google Nexus S USB Drivers for Windows 7 64Bit

Tags: usb, samsung-nexus-s

Anyone knows how to get the Google Nexus S to be recognized by the Windows OS. The only option I could find was to download the Android SDK and then use the driver from there, but unfortunately, it is a very big download and I wish to find a faster way to connect and check the files and folders on my Nexus S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The USB Driver for Windows is available for download as an optional SDK component. You need the driver only if you are developing on Windows and want to connect an Android-powered device (ADP, Nexus One, or Nexus S) to your development environment over USB.

Are you going to develop android app or just want to browse the internal memory?

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Comment: The problem with the link that you have provided is that, it requires the SDK to be downloaded and installed on your system. This is the thing which I wish to avoid for now.

Comment: The link on that page does seem to point to an 8.3MB USB driver which works fine on my system without downloading the SDK. Here's the direct link: https://dl-ssl.google.com//android/repository/latest_usb_driver_windows.zip