# Trying to install ADB USB Drivers, but Nexus is never appearing in Device Manager

Tags: usb, samsung-nexus-s, adb, usb-drivers

I'm trying to install the google-adb-drivers.zip file ([obtained here](http://dottech.org/downloads/google-adb-drivers.zip)) on a Windows 7 64-bit system. The phone is the Nexus S 9020T. USB connectivity works correctly for file transfer mode. When I enable debugging, I expect to see "Nexus" appear under "Other Devices" in Device Manager, but it doesn't. After checking USB Debugging under "Developer Options" in the phone, the computer makes the USB disconnected sound.

I was able to load the drivers on a different Windows 7 32-bit system, but that's not the system I want to use.

Why is the debugging port not being recognized on the 64 bit system?

I saw the [other post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16336/google-nexus-s-usb-drivers-for-windows-7-64bit) with a link to download the SDK, but I also would like to avoid installing the entire SDK unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the proper USB driver via the SDK Manager (which is the the tool you will run when installing the SDK).

The first step in installing the SDK, is starting the 'SDK Manager", and downloading an Android API package (ie. the code to develop for a specific API)

In the list of options, is an 'Extras' section - that contains the official USB driver for Android developer devices (of which the Nexus S is one).  Download that driver for best results.

You won't need to install the whole SDK using this method, but will need to start down that path, in order to get the proper driver.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Google's SDK [download](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) page:

This caught my eye under the section '**OEM Drivers**'

> The Galaxy Nexus driver, however, is distributed by Samsung (listed as
>   model SCH-I515).

Might be worth a shot to try that instead.

The alternative is to try this other USB download from the same site [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html).

The final [linky](http://www.androidsim.net/2009/08/how-to-1-how-to-install-usb-driver-on.html) to an alternative site to get this to work can be found here which comes with a edited minimal SDK download purely to get the drivers to work.

If not, then why not temporarily download the whole SDK (*have no choice here and is totally unavoidable*) and just extract the USB drivers from there and wipe the SDK instead, and if you do, be sure to make a backup copy of the USB drivers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Download the proper SDK API for Nexus and more-over you have to download the proper driver, if you have already installed the driver please uninstall it and then reinstall the driver, then it will work fine as I faced the same problem a couple of months ago. But this option worked for me.